# Flutter display user information using firebase auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I would like to display the uid and email from Firebase Auth (just used for auth only!) in my Drawer.

I have this method to return the uid :

```
static Future<String> getUID() async {
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return user!.uid;
}
```

And this is my Drawer :

```
class DrawerMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final String pageName;

  const DrawerMenu({Key? key, required this.pageName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DrawerMenuState createState() => _DrawerMenuState();
}

class _DrawerMenuState extends State<DrawerMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(MaterialLocalizations.of(context));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
      body: Center(
        child: DashboardPage(),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0), children: <Widget>[
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text(LoginPageService.getUID().toString()),      // HERE HERE HERE HERE 
            accountEmail: Text('random@gmail.com'),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/random.jpg'),
            ),
            otherAccountsPictures: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                child: Text('A'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
              ),
              CircleAvatar(
                child: Text('R'),
              ),
            ],
            onDetailsPressed: () {},
...
...
...
```

I know that `LoginPageService.getUID()` will return a Future, so yes it should not be used like that.

But i don't know what's the best way for doing it and where to put the code.. in the widget ? or elsewhere ?

Should i use .then((value).... to get the uid..

Let me know if you have experience with it, and how you did it

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the answer of @Youri you can do this :

```
static Future<User?> getCurrentUser() async {
    return await auth.currentUser;
}
```

And in your drawer :

```
String? uid, name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    LoginPageService.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        uid = user?.uid;
        email = user?.email;
      });
    });
}
```

And then you can use it like that :

```
accountName: Text(name.toString()),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `FutureBuilder` for any async code. This widget automatically rebuilds whenever the status of the provided `Future` changes.

Please checkout this widget of the week video from Flutter for more information on this Widget.

[FutureBuilder (Flutter Widget of the Week)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)